# Drop Permission From App

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have an app that used CardIO to import a credit card via camera. We've since removed this feature and the camera permission but it still shows up in the Play Store as needing access to the camera. The permission has been removed from the manifest. How do we remove it from the Play Store?

Comment: This is a curious question.  Are you sure that is really the case?  Like, when you download the app, is it telling you that the permissions are the same?  Because normally it alerts the user with something like, "This app NOW requires THESE permissions."

Comment: Are you looking in the developer or the Play Store itself? How long ago did you update the app?

Comment: We released a new version with the camera permissions removed. When I go to download it from the store it still says it needs the camera. Thanks for your help.